# Android Fragment's Options Menu Not Showing up

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment that I want to show in a container in an activity. The problem is that the menu options of the fragment aren't showing up.
Here is the activity code where I add the fragment: I tried .add and .replace but both same result:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    GridFragment gridFragment = new GridFragment();

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, gridFragment, TAG_GRID_FRAGMENT)
            .commit();
}
```

The Activity's xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/container" 
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
tools:context="appfactory.app.movies.ui.MainActivity"
app:sharedElementTransitions="true" />
```

Here is the fragment's onCreate:

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

The fragment's onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
    @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_fragment, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

The fragment's menu shows up only when I hard code the fragment in the main xml, which I don't want to do. Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: The same setup works for me. If you try to post a simple project with that behaviour that would be nice (i think you'd find yourself not able to do that).

Answer (score 0):

Call `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)` before menu `clear()` and `inflate()` method.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);    
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_fragment, menu);

}
```

Comment: @fullMoon: If my solution solves your problem then please upvote and mark it as accepted answer. Thank you~